# link_to doesn't work, controller appears as a html attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have been googling last 2 hours and unfortunately I cannot fix this, though I thought it must be easy.

```
<%= link_to 'Log Out', {:controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'index'} do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out link-icon"></i>
<% end %>
```

This the code I have. So, I need "Log Out" link to appear with log-out icon, which is from bootstrap. But HTML output of this code is this:

```
<a controller="static_pages" action="index" href="Log Out">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out link-icon"></i>
</a>
```

I tried many ways to fix this, but I also tried removing "do" so, I can see if it causes the problem. This is the link after I removed "do":

```
<%= link_to 'Log Out', {:controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'index'} %>
```

HTML output of this is:

```
<a href="/">Log Out</a>
```

It doesn't make sense. Because I have same link_to in my footer and it works. Footer:

```
<%= link_to 'Log In', {:controller => 'users', :action => 'login'} %>
```

Footer output:

```
<a href="/users/login">Log In</a>
```

So, why this isn't working in another page? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a block to the link_to helper this will be a body for it.

```
<%= link_to :controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'index' do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out link-icon"></i>
  Log Out
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, everything works except href. This is the HTML output: <a href="/">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out link-icon"></i>
                  Log Out
</a>

Comment: @cyonder checkout your routes. The preferable way is to use path instead explicit set controller and action , e.g. 'static_pages_path'

Comment: I was using match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post] but now, I will organize my paths individually and use path instead. Thank you.